# C++ concepts and template specialization; how to get a user-friendly compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

I have two (or more) templates that can each adapt a specific set of classes, identified by a concept. To make it possible for the two templates to have the same name, they must be specializations.

```
template< typename T >
struct pin_in { static_assert( always_false<T>::value, . . . ); };  

template< is_pin_in T >
struct pin_in< T > . . .

template< is_pin_in_out T >
struct pin_in< T > . . .
```

This works OK when one of the specializations match. When none match the base template is selected, and I get the assertion failure. The mechanism works. I love concepts!

But the error message I get (GCC 7.2.0) points to the assertion. Can I somehow make the base template not be selected, so I would get an error message that tells that no template matched the argument class?

Comment: Why don't you can add a message (2nd argument) to the static assert?

Comment: Of course I have, that's the . . . But the primary error message still points to the assert, not to the line that caused it.

Comment: The compiler sometimes adds a backtrace in the form of _in instantiation of Object_ and _required from here_, where it points where the instantiations were taking place.

Comment: Both gcc/clang give the 2 interesting places: the `static_assert` and place of instantiation [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ac3901063de436e). (I prefer clang message).

Comment: You can omit definition of general case: `template <typename T>
struct pin_in;`, so you would have an error for no definition instead of `static_assert`.

Comment: I can't try clang because it doesn't support concepts. GCC gives (as secondary location) not the place of instnatiation but the place where the instatiated type is first used, which is not very helpful.

Comment: Omitting the general definition gives an error at the first use, that is GOOD. It is a (small) pity that the error is "bla bla bla incomplete type". So far this seems the best solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hurray, I found a solution! What you need is to have the main template constrained:

```
template <class T>
    requires is_pin_in<T> || is_pin_in_out<T>
struct pin_in {};


template <is_pin_in T>
struct pin_in<T> {};

template <is_pin_in_out T>
struct pin_in<T> {};
```

And you get a good diagnostic message:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'auto test()':
> 29 : <source>:29:16: error: template constraint failure
>      pin_in<char> a;
>                 ^
> 29 : <source>:29:16: note:   constraints not satisfied
> 7 : <source>:7:24: note: within 'template<class T> concept const bool is_pin_in<T> [with T = char]'
>  constexpr concept bool is_pin_in = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
>                         ^~~~~~~~~
> 7 : <source>:7:24: note: 'std::is_same_v' evaluated to false
> 9 : <source>:9:24: note: within 'template<class T> concept const bool is_pin_in_out<T> [with T = char]'
>  constexpr concept bool is_pin_in_out = std::is_same_v<T, unsigned>;
>                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 9 : <source>:9:24: note: 'std::is_same_v' evaluated to false
> Compiler exited with result code 1
> ```

well, my message is with some dummy constraints, but you get the point

Comment: Nice! Concepts to the rescue.

Comment: But there is one small problem: this solution is closed in the sense that I can't lateron add a specialization for let's say is_pin_foo whithout also changing the base template. But a tag type in the classes that are acceptable might solve that. But that might cause the reverse problem: a decorator template written lateron would need to retrofit the existing classes with its marker. Unless it would enumerate them in the requires... I'll play with this one!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I would just create a concept that makes sense for `pin_in`. E.g. `template <class T> constexpr concept bool is_any_pin_in = is_pin_in<T> || is_pin_in_out<T>`

Comment: What I tried to say is that I don't want to make the list pin_in<> implementations closed. But then I realised that this is all within the namespeace of my library, so any extensions would be written by me, so no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use std::enable_if to remove the base template from overload resolution.
Something like this:

```
template< typename T >
struct pin_in<typename std::enable_if<false>::type> {};  

template< is_pin_in T >
struct pin_in<typename std::enable_if<true>::type>< T > . . .

template< is_pin_in_out T >
struct pin_in<typename std::enable_if<true>::type>< T > . . .
```

Comment: That is sort of what I was lloking for, but it gives an error on the first pin_in: 'pin_in is not a class template'